# Python multiprocessing.Process() constructor doesn't work as expected

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I used pypacker package to write a simple packet monitoring app. After adding the required iptables rule it listens to the specified queues and monitors the traffic:

```
"""
Interceptor example using ICMP

ADD this rule:
sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -p icmp -j NFQUEUE --queue-balance 0:2
"""
import time
from multiprocessing import Process
import os
from pypacker import interceptor
from pypacker.layer3 import ip

class TrafficMonitor(object):
    # ICMP Echo request intercepting
    def verdict_cb(self, ll_data, ll_proto_id, data, ctx):
        # ip1 = ip.IP(data)
        ip1 = ip.IP(data)


        print('\n---------->Packet recieved:\n\t source ip:%s , the dst ip:%s, \n\npacket_info:%s '
            %(ip1.src_s, ip1.dst_s, ip1))
        return ip1.bin(), interceptor.NF_ACCEPT

    def dpi_start(self, queue_id):
        print('queue', queue_id)
        ictor = interceptor.Interceptor()
        # queue = [0, 1, 2]
        ictor.start(self.verdict_cb, queue_ids=queue_id)


def start_int():
    monitor = TrafficMonitor()
    proc = Process(target=monitor.dpi_start, args=([0, 1, 2],))
    proc.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True :
        a = input('press y to start: ')
        if a == 'y':
            start_int()

        elif a == 'x':
            os._exit(0)
```

When I start a new process using the following function, the process starts and the function dpi_start() is executed but doesn't work as expected (i.e. it doesn't intercept any packet)

```
def start_int():
    monitor = TrafficMonitor()
    proc = Process(target=monitor.dpi_start, args=([0, 1, 2],))
    proc.start()
```

However, when I change the above function to the below code by explicitly storing the function call into a variable then pass this variable to Process() everything works as expected:

```
def start_int():
    monitor = TrafficMonitor()
    queue = [0, 1, 2]
    start = monitor.dpi_start(queue)
    proc = Process(target=start)
    proc.start()
```

I am curious what is the reason for this and why the Process() constructor doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Your second example shouldn't work, because `dpi_start` doesn't return anything. Additionally, why is `dpi_start` a method instead of a function?

Comment: would you explain more... because the second code works. I am trying to use this code as a module for some other code. Why `dpi_start` should not be a method?

Comment: Since `monitor.dpi_start` doesn't return anything, the value of `start` is `None`. So *nothing* is being run... Look at the multiprocessing docs. Since `TrafficMonitor` doesn't create instance variables, (there is no `__init__`) there is no reason to gather `dpi_start` and `verdict_cb` into a class; it doesn't achieve anything.

Comment: OK, in the doc what should I look for? in the doc there are some examples where the function doen't return anything; also, ictor.start() is a call back function, so it is a loop. yes at the moment it doesn't have any __init__ but later on I will expand this class. would you tell me, why the first example doesn't work?

Comment: Look at the documentation for `class multiprocessing.Process`, especially the `target` parameter.